# Rails form for nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, has-many, nested-attributes

I'm trying to figure out how to change the standard rails scaffolding form so that it works for a nested model.

So here's the deal: checklists have many checks. But when I do the standard scaffolded form:

```
<%= form_for(@check) do |f| %>
  <% if @check.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@check.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this check from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
       <% @check.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
   <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I get this error (accessing /checklists/1/checks/new):

```
undefined method `checks_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000101795070>:0x000001017913a8>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@check) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @check.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
```

What should I change in this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Railscasts' Nested Model Form](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) would be a good tutorial for you.